# How to uniquely identify records where condition is met in two different subset of values in the same column mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table where licenses are kept both for US and Canadian states. Column name is license_state it can have both US and Canadian state. I am looking to find records in this licenses table where a person has atleast one license in both US and Canadian states.

Table consists of the following columns . User_id , License, License_state. License state has all 50 us states plus 13 canadian states. I need to find those users who have both US and canadian states. Sample US states (CA,NY) sample Canadian state ( AB, BC) –

For example I want to see if there is any record where record has values in both US and Canadian state.

Comment: please add a [mre]  so that we can better understand what you are looking for

Comment: Table consists of the following columns . User_id , License, License_state. License state has all 50 us states plus 13 canadian states. I need to find those users who have both US and canadian states. Sample US states (CA,NY) sample Canadian state ( AB, BC)

Comment: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68006453/edit) your question